# Anonymization Standards

Tags: anonymity

I'm interested in data anonymization techniques and scores for the quality of data anonymization in "the real world". I was told this is also part of cryptography.

**What I know**: In theory one can use k-anonymity, l-diversity or t-closeness to define the quality. Also the [open gda score](https://www.gda-score.org/) could be used. Common techniques are generalization, synthetic data and deleting data. I also studied the laws and found out, that there are no strict rules which state a standard for anonymization (I only found out, that the EuGH once said that reidentification should be "hard")

**My question**: How is anonymization done in practice? What standards are common? Which scores for quality are used and why?

Comment: Anonymity doesn't make sense without any context. I think you should precise the use-case.

Comment: The main context I found in the literature is data in tabular form. For example csv or xlxx files. I don't mean anonymization done by VPN, Proxies, the Onion network or anything like that. I think the correct term for what I'm interested in is "data anonymization" (I added that to the question)

Comment: And/or [differential privacy?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-privacy)

Comment: @PaulUszak Is it a standard?